# Как называется словарь, который хранит все возможные слова английского алфавита?

Tags: поиск

Забыл название этого "словаря", который хранит последовательности всех возможных английских символов в следующем формате, из-за чего также хранит все возможные слова английского алфавита:
a
ab
ba
abc
bca
cba
cab
bac

И так до бесконечности
Как это называется? Забыл слово, очень нужно.

Comment: string permutation dictionary / лексикографический?

Comment: это перестановки элементов.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Данный словарь назывался **hyperwebster**

Answer (score -1):

Словаря, который хранит последовательности "до бесконечности" нет в природе.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/424233)

Comment: @Coder перечитайте вопрос внимательнее.

Comment: при всем уважении - это не ответ, это категоричное Ваше мнение.

Comment: @Coder любой ответ это чьё-то мнение, но вы всё же перечитайте вопрос.

Comment: все-таки 2+2=4 это больше ответ, а не мнение) ТС говорит в вопросе, что он знал, но забыл - значит, таковой существует - хотя, возможно, вопрос несколько расплывчат - в любом случае, ТС нужно напоминание о чем-т о реально существующем, что он когда-то знал. Если это не фантазии, конечно. Опять же - и в этом случае ответ либо есть, либо неопределен. Имхо. PS Минусы не ставил, если что.